# How to stop Forefront from blocking my program?

Tags: anti-virus, microsoft-forefront, whitelist

(I'm not sure if this should go on StackOverflow.)

I have a program running at a customer site for ten years now. It takes their data and uses it to fill out web forms. It works by attaching itself to IE using `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Now the customer has chosen Microsoft Forefront as a corporate standard, and it's broken something. As best I can tell, it lets my program run, but intercepts the call to `SetWindowsHookEx()` as if my program were malware.

The program works correctly when I choose Run As Adminstrator, but that's not a practical workaround. I've started rewriting the app to use a more modern method of interacting with IE, but that's going to take a long time, and the customer needs a fix now.

Is there some way of configuring Forefront to trust my program? Does it have a way of whitelisting me?

This is happening under both Vista and Win7. The app is unsigned, and there's no Application Manifest (it's unmanaged C++).